# How to upload to google drive with python without authentication?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api

I want to upload files to Google Drive with Google Script and Python.

I don't want to do this with API because it's with JSON file and requesting a password to google account.

I want to send from the Python file without a JSON file and without requesting a google account.

I want to create a script in google script that will upload the file to the site.

I found how to do it with html:

```
function saveFile(data,name,folderName) { 
   var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';'));

   var file = Utilities.newBlob(
     Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)), 
     contentType, 
     name
   ); //does the uploading of the files
   DriveApp.getFolderById(childFolderIdA).createFile(file);
}
```

But I did not find how to do it with python.

How do I send file with file to this code?

Comment: How do you even want to send the file if you're not authenticated? Google needs to know who you are, unless you want someone to spam your account and use all your free Google Drive space...

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by publishing a headless web app(without a UI) to run as "Me"(you)  with access: "Anyone, even anonymous".

#### Server side:

```js
function doPost(e){
  const FOLDER_ID = '###FOLDER_ID###';
  const name = e.parameter.name;
  saveFile(e.postData.contents,name,FOLDER_ID);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Success');
}

function saveFile(data,name,id) { 
    const blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64DecodeWebSafe(data));
    DriveApp.getFolderById(id)
    .createFile(blob.setName(name))
}
```

#### Client side:

```py
import requests, base64
url = '###WEB_APP_PUBLISHED_URL###'
name = '###FILENAME###'
requests.post(url+'?name='+name,data=base64.urlsafe_b64encode(open('##UPLOAD FILE PATH##','rb').read()))
```

#### Note:

- Anyone who knows or guesses the web app url can upload to your drive. The entropy of the url is the only security.

#### References:

- [Webapp guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Requests library](https://3.python-requests.org/)

Comment: I think that your proposal can answer of OP's question. If I can add an information, how about this addition? I think that your script can be used for the text files. But when the binary data is sent to Web Apps, the data cannot be correctly decoded by the problem of character code because the data is used as string data at the Web Apps side. So in this case, as a workaround, how about using the base64 data for sending the data? And the data is decoded to the binary at Google side. By this, both text and binary data can be used. If I misunderstood OP's question, I apologize.

Comment: it's work.

I have another question.

If I want to transfer either the file name or additional information.
How can I forward this to a post.
Every way I tried, I got an error.