# Within the google docs API, Can I insert a picture from my computer without being from a webpage?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to use screenshots that I receive from a python script using selenium to be able to add it or send it through to a google doc API to be able to add it to a google apps script.

Is this a possible using the google docs script api?

I found this example that I think may work, but I am not sure if an online picture is needed or not.

https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/images

TLDR:
Can the api call a local .png or does it have to be a `http://` like the example?

Comment: I think that the image must be online. If you're using selenium, isn't the image already online?

Comment: yes, but if I took a screenshot it can only be a .png

Comment: You may push it using [tag:google-drive-api]. See [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert) and use file's `exportLink` to have a online link. Alternatively you can easily publish a google apps script web-app, which can receive post requests  to create a file: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56810778)

Comment: Thank you very much....That might just work...you are a life saver