# Want to implement Google Sheet API in Swift 4 to write in sheet

Tags: ios, swift, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have an app and now I want to store some data in Google Sheet using Google Sheet APIs. I don't have Google sign in in the app and I enabled API in developer console.

I checked other answers on Stack Overflow but they are using Google sign in to get access token.

Here is my code:

```
func writeGoogleSheet() {
    
    let sheetID = "GoogleSheet ID"
    let range = "A3:B4"
    let requestParams = [
        "values": [
            ["hi1", "hi2"],
            ["hi3", "hi4"]
            ]
        ]
 
    let requestURL =  "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/\(sheetID)/values/\(range)?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&key=API_Key"
    let req = AF.request(requestURL, method: .put, parameters: requestParams, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
    req.responseJSON { response in debugPrint(response) }
    
}
```

[Response Body]:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

So please guide me how to implement this without Google sign in? I have one Google sheet where I want to write data.

Comment: So you wanted to enter inside the room w/o opening the door.

Comment: Yes. As I don't have google sign in in the app. Is there any way, I can automatically sign in to google when app is launched to default account? @dahiya_boy

Comment: This is not how things work. First you need to register your app, get access token , use access token to hit APIs.

Comment: So for getting access token, I don't need to implement google sign in right? I can get access token from developer console once register the app to that.

Comment: Which blog you are referring bcz on official doc there is no such access token ->> [check](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading)

Comment: I think access token should be passed in http header.

Comment: Header access token is used to secure your APIs from external malware. This access token must be provided by your API developer.

Comment: I added response I am getting from the API. Please check updated post. @dahiya_boy

Comment: Open up your Google sheet to public edit or you'd need access token.

Comment: @TheMaster Am still getting same response. I made my sheet public.

Comment: Do you have any sample that I can check if I am missing something?

Comment: You'd still need to use [api key](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#APIKey). On a side note, why don't you put Google sign in in your app?

Comment: okay. I modified it like, https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/sheet_id/values/A3:B4?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED?key=api_key

Is it correct?@TheMaster

Comment: Query parameters should be joined with `&` : `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/sheet_id/values/A3:B4?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&key=api_key`

Comment: I tried but same response. @TheMaster

Comment: Is the sheet shared with "Anyone can edit?" And your script doesn't have apikey. Could you [edit] to show latest script?

Comment: Yes. It is public edit and I updated my question with api_key in it. @TheMaster

Comment: Could you [try the api here at the bottom of the page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) with your spreadsheet id and uncheck oauth to make sure it works with only api key? If that doesn't work, I'm afraid only reading data is possible(Writing would require oauth)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56810778/

Comment: Yes, writing requires oauth. How I can get my account approved for oauth? @TheMaster

Comment: What does this app do? Need to know use case here. If you want to write to a sheet that users own, you need users to sign in. If you own the sheet, you can delegate access to a service account. See [complete example](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

Comment: This app is for getting user details using forms and save it to sheet own by me. @TheMaster

Comment: Is it possible to embed a Google form?