# Is there a way we can upload files to google drive folder through CMD in windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd, google-drive-api, scheduled-tasks

I have a certain large amount of files that I have to upload to Google Drive often. So I was thinking whether there is a way we can achieve this through CMD in windows (so I can create a bat file and schedule it as a task in the task scheduler) just like AWS has AWS Command Line Interface ? Is there a way to upload files to Drive through CMD in windows or any other way by which this functionality can be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer:

*You can do this by using the Google Drive API Python library and then run it from a batch file.*

#### More Information:

Google has great documentation on how to connect to the Drive API using Python over on their [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) page. You will need to follow the steps which includes creating a Cloud Platform project and enabling the Drive API, but once this is done you can set up a `.py` file which connects to your Drive.

The aforementioned Quickstart gives an example on how to list files, but instead you will have to use the upload methods. There is more information on the types of upload method [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) including examples.

With this all done, you can then set up a nice little batch file to execute your python script:

```
cd "C:\Users\Rafa\Documents\python_scripts"
python drive_upload.py
pause
```

First time you run this you will be prompted to authorise access - but once it's done and your access token is saved you can run your batch as you like.

**NB:** There is ***absolutely no way*** of accessing the Drive API natively with just batch commands, you will need to run a program which connects to the API *using* batch instead.

#### References:

- [Python Quickstart | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)
- [Upload file data | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
- [Files | Google Drive API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)

Comment: Please try to refrain from answering questions considered off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I would disagree with *NB: There is absolutely no way of accessing the Drive API without using a client library* See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808846/ @Compo The closure is debatable.

Comment: @TheMaster, my reading from above is that "Batch does not have this functionality natively." is an important omission from your part quoted paragraph. Feel free to debate the closure in the appropriate place, should you wish to, _(that is not here in the comments below someone else's answer)_, but technically the answer to the question posed is either `Yes` or `No`. This is a site dedicated to specific coding issues, whereas Super User, would provide a more realistic platform for a generic software related question such as this.

Comment: @Compo I guess it was not clear: The first part of my comment is directed against Rafa and only the part of the comment about the closure is directed  towards you.   It would  be reasonable to interpret  the question as "If yes, how" and not just a "yes" or "no" question. The  question  doesn't limit itself to the native functionality of "Batch" either. This is not a valid question for SuperUser either as it does involve coding/programming. I could agree that research is lacking, but that's not a valid close reason.

Comment: My comment @TheMaster was clear; you're disagreeing with only part of Rafa's comment, i.e. not taking it in the context it was posted, and therefore assumed intended. As for the rest of it, I've already told you that this is not the correct place to debate the closure notice, so please do not. Comments are not for that, or for extended discussion, as well you know.

Comment: @TheMaster You're right, it was a bad phrasing on my part. I meant that batch doesn't have this functionality natively rather than directly *needing* to always use a client library. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Can I run python programs without human authrization ? I just want to write my username and password in code and run it with crontab.